# How to remove more videos div in youtube api embed code

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have a issue in my website. I have integrated Youtube `api` embed script code.

When I pause video "ytp pause overlay" div showing there. I need to hide that when I pause that video.

Comment: Please reply someone

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54397284/4694757 and the code here :https://jsfiddle.net/ibrth/0zx7o6rs/40/