# Hide related videos Youtube Iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to hide *related videos* that shows up when you pause a video but as I found out from similar questions that as of **September 25th 2018** there is no way to disable the *related videos* from displaying.

> The effect of the change is that you will not be able to disable
>   related videos. However, you will have the option of specifying that
>   the related videos shown in the player should be from the same channel
>   as the video that was just played.
>
> To be more specific:
>
> Prior to the change, if the parameter's value is set to 0, then the
>   player does not show related videos. After the change, if the rel
>   parameter is set to 0, the player will show related videos that are
>   from the same channel as the video that was just played.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SL_A_SH/x0y7gzaj/23/).

Also the parameter `showinfo=0` dosen't work anymore which was used to hide the video title, watch later button and the share button. It is **deprecated as of September 25, 2018** but somehow [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/introduction-to-algebra/overview-hist-alg/v/origins-of-algebra) is still able to hide those including the related videos. Are they using a different API?

Hiding the related videos altogether like Khan Academy does or overlaying a thumbnail on top to hide the related videos will work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I remove all the js code from your jsfiddle it works for me well. https://streamable.com/h8261

Comment: The person who downvoted, can you tell me why? What needs to improved?

Comment: @MoshFeu Streamable is blocked in my country

Comment: Which service are you using?

Comment: Service for sharing videos? like Streamable?

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know about other alternatives to streamable

Comment: Are you see more videos in this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/jvz1etpr/1/ Because I don't (And I don't have adblock on jsfiddle)

Comment: No obviously because that channel does not have any other videos. When I give a different channel that has multiple videos then more videos is coming. I will add a different video it in my fiddle

Comment: Check the fiddle now. You can see more videos while pausing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found an open source player which does hide all the related videos including the title, the share and watch later button.

The player name is [Plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="plyr__video-embed" id="player">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9C1leq--_wM??origin=https://plyr.io&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen allowtransparency allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</div>
```

**You can initialize it with:**

```
const player = new Plyr('#player', {});

// Expose player so it can be used from the console
window.player = player;
```

**CSS to hide the related videos:**

```
.plyr__video-embed iframe {
    top: -50%;
    height: 200%;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SL_A_SH/x0y7gzaj/25/). It's working perfectly for me.

Comment: This is not working on my end. it's disapying related video after finishing that clicp.

Answer (score 3):

From September 25, 2018 youtube has changed their API. So, you can't disable the related videos but you can specify a list that can be shown.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel

I already tried all possible answers provided below You can try the code here:https://jsfiddle.net/ibrth/0zx7o6rs/62/ and https://jsfiddle.net/ibrth/z9tk1q3r/

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        videoId: '0sDg2h3M1RE',
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            playlist: 'taJ60kskkns,FG0fTKAqZ5g',
            rel:0,
            enablejsapi:1,
            modestbranding: 1, showinfo: 0, ecver: 2
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize
        }
    });
}
```

I found the answer here:

[Youtube Javascript API - disable related videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418028/youtube-javascript-api-disable-related-videos/13418293) and
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102974/how-to-remove-the-related-videos-at-end-of-youtube-embedded-video

Comment: I tried the [link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/rJLICm3XE) for the demo. It still enters the Pause state while using the progress bar.

Comment: @DragonBorn you can see the code here and it works: https://onlinegdb.com/rJLICm3XE

Comment: No it doesn't. [Run it](https://onlinegdb.com/SJ81w427E) and click anywhere on the progress bar and you can see an alert popup when it shouldn't.

Comment: @DragonBorn could you tell me which browser that you used.

Comment: I used Google Chrome

Comment: @i_th I'm not sure I understand. In the jsfiddle you just updated, there is no progress bar at all and in the rest of the examples, in pause I can see the related videos.

Comment: @MoshFeu it can't be disabled as mentioned in the answer  but when I pause the video there is no related video https://ibb.co/3pKKd1s

Comment: @MoshFeu I think the adblock prevented it.

Comment: Make sense :) I blocked ad block in jsfiddle.

Comment: I can understand that google has changed that but I am still getting those related videos but KhanAcademy are able to hide it.

Comment: @DragonBorn KhanAcademy maybe uses a commercial channel and they still provide them this service. See this:https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel

Comment: That might be it.

Comment: @DragonBorn if you have your own channel, you can turn off the advertisement and it may work: http://orgspring.com/turn-off-ads-youtube-videos/ 

good luck.

Comment: From KhanAcademy's own site, both google branding and the related videos overlay are completely absent. But if you take a KhanAcademy video and embed it on another site, they appear as expected. The youtube dev docs don't seem to mention anything about this - they say that the related videos (and modest branding) will now always appear.